# Is the Fallout series all set in the same timeframe?

Tags: fallout-series

I was recently playing Fallout 4, and then noticed that effectively, everything is still the same in all the games - same setting, same technology, same Brotherhood, same ol' Codsworth.

So are all the Fallout games set in the same time period (give or take a few decades)?

Comment: I'm quite sure all the PipBoys in Fallout 3, NV and 4 had the time and date in the Map Section with the last first 2 digits dropped from the year being `22` because the great was was in 2077 and it had been ~200 years since

Comment: "same ol' Codsworth"... huh? I assume you're referring to the Mr. Handy model of robot, and not Codsworth himself?

Comment: Fallout 4 happens subsequent to Fallout 3. There a scientist character that is involved with the Brotherhood of Steel during 3 that leaves them over some disagreements on a project she worked on for them. In 4 the BoS sends you on a mission to re-recruit her.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Based on the image found on the [timeline wikia page](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline), Fallout 3, 4, and New Vegas all took place within 10-20 years of each other. However, Fallout 2 took place 30-40 years before them, Fallout Tactics and Fallout: Brotherhood of Steel took place roughly 30 years before that, and lastly (firstly?), the original Fallout took place 40 years prior.

So, while no game takes place more than half a century from another, the full timeline of the games spans roughly 120 years. As for whether they all fall within the same timeframe, it really depends on why you mean by the same timeframe. Considering the amount of time between the Great War and the latest game in the timeline (Fallout 4), the games are pretty spread out. It's highly unlikely that any non-ghoul (and non-Cabot) humans have lived through the entirety of the Fallout series, but it's likely that characters could live long enough to make cameos in other games (in fact, some do).

[image: fallout timeline]

Comment: Perhaps most notably, Harold (a ghoul) can be found in Fallouts 1, 2 and 3 (and some spinoffs) and Tandi (a human) is present in Fallout 1 and 2 as an important character (and appears on a banknote in New Vegas).

Comment: Marcus (a super mutant) appears in Fallout 2 and New Vegas http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Marcus

Comment: Perhaps a more clear way of wording it would be that "no more than 50 years elapse without a game"?

Comment: @DoktorJ I mean that would work, but doesn't my edit already take care of it?

Comment: Maybe it's just me but I read "another" to mean "any other", e.g. all games took place within a 50 year time frame. Another alternative might be "Every Fallout game takes place within 50 years of at least one other game in the series" ?

Comment: @DoktorJ I am pretty sure that "another" is simply a contraction of "an other". (By that I mean, I wrote this and then googled to double check)

Comment: Grammatically speaking, yes it is... but in the context I had to do a double-take to understand what was meant. Maybe it's just my pain meds though? :)